# Array of Functional Components doesn't append props content as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-functional-component

I want to add an array of `<TokenFeed/>` functional components to the `<Feeds/>` component. The problem is that when I do, the `onClick()` event that passes some text to my `<App/>` doesn't work as expected. The array version of `<TokenFeed/>` when clicked, will replace my `<input/>` text rather than appending to the end of it.

On the contrary, when I add a copy of `<TokenFeed/>` in the return of `<Feeds/>`,
and click the button, it works fine.

How can I fix this?

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/feeds-efs1f?file=/src/Feeds.jsx)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Feeds } from "./Feeds";

export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [showFeeds, setShowFeeds] = useState();

  function createFeeds(e) {
    if (e._reactName === "onClick" && showFeeds === undefined) {
      setShowFeeds(
        <Feeds
          value={(val) => {
            setInputValue(inputValue + val);
            createFeeds("");
          }}
        />
      );
    } else {
      setShowFeeds(undefined);
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Message"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
      <button onClick={(e) => createFeeds(e)}>Create Feeds</button>
      {showFeeds}
    </>
  );
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import { TokenFeed } from "./TokenFeed";

let tokenFeedArr = [];

export const Feeds = (props) => {
  if (tokenFeedArr.length === 0) {
    tokenFeedArr.push(
      <TokenFeed
        key={"1"}
        onClick={() => props.value("Array")}
        tokenName={"Array"}
        tokenPrice={"Test"}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <section>
      {/* This doesn't work */}
      {tokenFeedArr}

      {/* This does work */}
      <TokenFeed
        key={"2"}
        onClick={() => props.value("Direct")}
        tokenName={"Direct"}
        tokenPrice={"Test"}
      />
    </section>
  );
};
```

```
import React from "react";

export const TokenFeed = (props) => {
  return (
    <section
      onClick={() => props.onClick()}
      style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow", width: "10%", textAlign: "center" }}
    >
      <h1>{props.tokenName}</h1>
      <p>{props.tokenPrice}</p>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: can you share what is the expected functionality ? how should it ideally work? eg when I type 'test' in input and press create feed, what should happen, and when I type append '2' to make it 'test2' How should the app behave ?

Comment: When create feed is clicked, you have the option to click Array and Direct.

I want to be able to click Array multiple times and have it output "Array" + the value that was already inside the input.

The Array button should work exactly like the Direct button does.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If rendering `TokenFeed` directly as a child is working, then what is the issue?

Comment: @ALegendsTale You're trying to push the JSX to an array that's outside the component and render it. BTW, storing JSX in the state is a bad idea

Comment: @DrewReese I plan on dynamically adding the ```TokenFeed``` elements so I needed an array

Comment: React 101, don't store JSX in state, or array, etc... store data and map that to the JSX you need. You'll avoid an entire class of React stale enclosure bugs this way.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for your help and tips! I'm still pretty new to React so I appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `let tokenFeedArr = [];` inside the `Feeds` component.

Instead of:

```
let tokenFeedArr = [];

export const Feeds = (props) => {
  if (tokenFeedArr.length === 0) {
    tokenFeedArr.push(
      <TokenFeed
        key={"1"}
        onClick={() => props.value("Array")}
        tokenName={"Array"}
        tokenPrice={"Test"}
      />
    );
  }
...
```

Try this:

```
export const Feeds = (props) => {
  const tokenFeedArr = [];
  if (tokenFeedArr.length === 0) {
    tokenFeedArr.push(
      <TokenFeed
        key={"1"}
        onClick={() => props.value("Array")}
        tokenName={"Array"}
        tokenPrice={"Test"}
      />
    );
  }
...
```

The reason the `tokenFeedArr` that is declared outside the `Feeds` component doesn't work has to do with JavaScript closures. Specifically the issue lies within the `value()` function that's inside instances of `TokenFeed` inside the `tokenFeedArr`.

The `value()` function that is passed to an instance of `TokenFeed` inside of the `tokenFeedArr` only has access to `inputValue` as it was when the component was mounted (which is an empty string). It's not connected to `inputValue` via React state, because it's outside of the scope of the exported component. This is true even though the `TokenFeed` components are pushed to `tokenFeedArr` inside the `Feeds` component. `tokenFeedArr` is still declared outside `Feeds`. The `setInputValue` function works, because of how the `useState` hook works, but the `inputValue` variable is just a variable and is subject to JavaScript closures/hoisting, which causes it to retain its original value.

Comment: You have it exactly backwards. Declared inside the component like this is the version that resets it each rendering. At least when it was declared outside it persisted, but because it isn't part of any state it doesn't trigger rerenders when updated.

Comment: @DrewReese Try opening the demo OP posted and implementing my solution, you'll see that it works. I think maybe my explanation is a little confusing though. The ```tokenFeedArr``` is not actually there as a way to manage state. I will try to update my answer to explain it more clearly.

Comment: @CarltonLindsay Thank you for the detailed explanation! It has really helped me a lot.